# R how to delete a sample from a vector

Tags: r

Let's say there is a vector `aa = c(1,1,1,2,2,2)` and I sample two random elements from it, for example, `1` and `2`, so I get a sample `c(1,2)`, let's call it `bb`.

Now in R is there a way to remove this sample from the vector `aa`. The `1` and `2` here are not positions of vectors and `aa[aa != bb]` will remove the entire vector since `1` and `2` cover all elements of `aa`. How do I just remove one `1` and `2` of each from this vector so `aa` becomes `c(1,1,2,2)`?

Comment: One solution would be to create a new column, `id`, from the row names, then sample and remove based on `id` instead of `aa`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a package called `vecsets` that does exactly what you are asking:

```
vecsets::vsetdiff( c(1,1,1,2,2,2), c(1,2) )
# [1] 1 1 2 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use the indices along `aa` for sampling `bb`

```
aa = c(1,1,1,2,2,2)

set.seed(42)
#Sample two indices along aa
inds = sample(seq_along(aa), 2)

bb = aa[inds]
bb
#[1] 2 2

#Everything in aa except bb
aa[-inds]
#[1] 1 1 1 2
```